# From $f(x)=o(\|x\|^m)$ to that m-order partial derivative equals $0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=0$ satisfying
>   $$f(x)=o(\|x\|^m)\,,\,x\to0$$
>   If all the $m$-order  partial derivatives exist, prove that the partial derivatives equal $0$ at the origin (or give a counterexample).

**My attempt**

Put $\phi(s)=f(sx_i)$. Thus $\phi$'s $m$-order derivative exists and $\phi(s)=o(s^m)$($s\to0$).

It implies that for $1\le k\le m$ we have
$$\frac{\partial^kf}{\partial x_i^k}(0)=\phi^{k}(0)=0$$

But how to deal with something like $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2}$? Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am here now. Did you try the $m=1$ case?   So assume that $f(x) = o(||x||)$ near zero, $f(0) = 0$ and $f$ has partial derivatives everywhere, then the partial derivatives at $0$ must be zero?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes, I tried it. When $m=1$ we have $\phi(s)=f(sx_i)$ is differentiable and $\phi(s)=o(|s|)$ with $\phi(0)=0$. Then I thought I have $\phi(s)=\phi(0)+\phi'(0)s+o(|s|)$ ($s \to 0$). Thus I thought $\phi'(0)=0$ which means that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(0)=0$.